# How to add Directions to my Google Api Maps feauture in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

My current code uses Google Maps Api and Google Autocomplete API to draw the directions on the map for the starting location and destination location.

I want to include directions along with this. How can I add directions in my code so that it will also add directions? This is what I want to implement:

Codepen for Directions example https://codepen.io/Shant7/pen/oNaLdap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaJwY.jpg)

Here is my code so far.
Codepen for my code https://codepen.io/ShayeraB/pen/gOpZqVL

```js
const timeElement = document.querySelector(".time");
const dateElement = document.querySelector(".date");

/**
 * @param {Date} date
 */
function formatTime(date) {
  const hours12 = date.getHours() % 12 || 12;
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();
  const isAm = date.getHours() < 12;

  return `${hours12.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${minutes
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, "0")} ${isAm ? "AM" : "PM"}`;
}

/**
 * @param {Date} date
 */
function formatDate(date) {
  const DAYS = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
  ];
  const MONTHS = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
  ];

  return `${DAYS[date.getDay()]}, ${
    MONTHS[date.getMonth()]
  } ${date.getDate()} ${date.getFullYear()}`;
}

setInterval(() => {
  const now = new Date();

  timeElement.textContent = formatTime(now);
  dateElement.textContent = formatDate(now);
}, 200);


let map;

window.initMap = function() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: 29.749907,
      lng: -95.358
    },
  });

  class AutocompleteDirectionsHandler {
    map;
    originPlaceId;
    destinationPlaceId;
    travelMode;
    directionsService;
    directionsRenderer;
    constructor(map) {
      this.map = map;
      this.originPlaceId = "";
      this.destinationPlaceId = "";
      this.travelMode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING;
      this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

      const originInput = document.getElementById("origin-input");
      const destinationInput = document.getElementById("destination-input");
      const modeSelector = document.getElementById("mode-selector");
      // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
      const originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        originInput, {
          fields: ["place_id"]
        }
      );
      // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
      const destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        destinationInput, {
          fields: ["place_id"]
        }
      );
      this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, "ORIG");
      this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, "DEST");
      this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
      this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(
        destinationInput
      );
      this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
    }
    // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
    // Autocomplete.
    setupClickListener(id, mode) {
      const radioButton = document.getElementById(id);

      radioButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        this.travelMode = mode;
        this.route();
      });
    }
    setupPlaceChangedListener(autocomplete, mode) {
      autocomplete.bindTo("bounds", this.map);
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        if (!place.place_id) {
          window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
          return;
        }

        if (mode === "ORIG") {
          this.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
        } else {
          this.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
        }

        this.route();
      });
    }
    route() {
      if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
        return;
      }

      const me = this;

      this.directionsService.route({
          origin: {
            placeId: this.originPlaceId
          },
          destination: {
            placeId: this.destinationPlaceId
          },
          travelMode: this.travelMode,
        },
        (response, status) => {
          if (status === "OK") {
            me.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
  
  
  //------------- Directon Code for Side panel---------------------
  // this.directionsRenderer.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));


  // function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
  //   const start = document.getElementById("origin-input");
  //   const end = document.getElementById("destination-input");
  
  //   directionsService
  //     .route({
  //       origin: start,
  //       destination: end,
  //       travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
  //     })
  //     .then((response) => {
  //       directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
  //     })
  //     .catch((e) => window.alert("Directions request failed"));
  // }

  new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map); 
}



window.initMap = initMap;



      
// [END maps_map_simple]
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */

 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;400;700&display=swap');

 #map {
    height: 80%;
    top: 30px;
    position: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 2em;
   
  }
  
  /* 
   * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
   */
  html,
  body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    top: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #808080;
    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    font-size: 120%;
  }
  
  #floating-panel {
  top: 60px;
  left: 200px;
  background: white;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3))
  }

  #directions {
    
    background: white;
    color: white;
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin: 1em;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3))
    }
  
 

  #destination-input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.4em;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 70%;
    width: 190px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  #origin-input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.4em;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 70%;
    width: 190px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  #submit {
    margin: .5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    height: 44px;
    width: 60px;
    outline: none;
    background: #7c7c7c2b;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    
  }

  #mode{
    margin: .5em;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 10%;



  }
  
  #warnings-panel {
    width: 70%;
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .datetime {

    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 50;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 90px;
    color: white;
    webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }
  
  .keyboard {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background: #b6b6b6d7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    user-select: none;
    transition: bottom 0.4s;
}

.keyboard--hidden {
    bottom: -100%;
}

.keyboard__keys {
    text-align: center;
}

.keyboard__key {
    height: 45px;
    width: 6%;
    max-width: 90px;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    background: rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.843);
    color: #1c1c1c;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}

.keyboard__key:active {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}

.keyboard__key--wide {
    width: 12%;
}

.keyboard__key--extra-wide {
    width: 36%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.keyboard__key--activatable::after {
    content: '';
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.keyboard__key--active::after {
    background: #08ff00;
}

.keyboard__key--dark {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
  

.sidebar
{
  top: 20px;
  background: white;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3))
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>DREAM MIRROR | Traffic </title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="traffic.css" />
</head>
<style>
  a {
    left: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  
  a:hover {
    color: #00A0C6;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  #map {
    height: 80%;
    width: 50%;
  }

  
</style>

<div class="datetime">
  <div class="time"></div>
  <div class="date"></div>
</div>
<a href="../homepage.html">Back</a>

<body>
  <div>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <b>Enter your Commute  </b>


      <b>  <br>
      

      <select id="mode">
        <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
        <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
        <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
        <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
      </select>

      <!-- Directions Panel for Side directions -->
      <div id="directions" style="position:absolute; left:1000px; top:200px; float: right;"></div> 
      <!-- Directions Panel for Side directions -->


    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
  &nbsp;

  

  
  

  <div id="directions-panel" style="width: 300px; float: right;"></div>
  <input type="text" id="origin-input" placeholder="Enter a location" class="use-keyboard-input">

  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <b> - </b>
  <input type="text" id="destination-input" placeholder="Enter a destination" class="use-keyboard-input">




  

  <!-- 
      The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
      document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
      and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
      with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
      -->
    <script src="traffic.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCrrT3Xs7zvfuWyBbCjFmcWaQnqwfZvSJw&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly" async defer></script>
  <script src="../keyboard/keyboard.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you attempting to add the directions "panel"?

Comment: @geocodezip Yes thats correct!

Comment: Your codesnippet has an error and your HTML in the codepen is invalid... presentational elements should appear in the `body`, **NOT** the `head`

Comment: Where is the HTML (where is the "panel" element?)? I don't see it in the codesnippet.  Where did you try to add the panel to the `DirectionsRenderer` in your code?

Comment: i just added the panel element for the Directions panel. Its labeled this ```<div id="directions" style="position:absolute; left:1000px; top:200px; float: right;"></div> ``` Also yes ```DirectionsRenderer``` is in my code but I did add the panel to it.

Comment: I added the setPanel() code from Google example to my Js code. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel#maps_directions_panel-javascript

Comment: I see a javascript error reported in your snippet: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setPanel')
    at window.initMap (js:498:27)` (and the autocomplete functionality seems to be broken).

Comment: @geocodezip I commented out the JavaScript code that was causing that error. It was the ```function calculateAndDisplayRoute``` code I copied from the Google example.